# Aplying JQuery mask dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a text field and when the user types the first char I have to apply one of two masks.

The rules are:

1. if the user types '#' the mask to be applied is '#9999999999'.
2. If the user types a number the mask to be applied is '999.999.999-99'.

The JavaScript that I generated is

```
(function () {
  var oldVal;
  $('#id').on('keypress paste textInput input', function () {
    var val = this.value;
    if ((val != oldVal) && (val.length == 1)) {
      oldVal = val;
      if(oldVal == '#'){
        $('#id').mask('999999999');
        $('#id').val(oldVal)
      }else{
        $('#id').mask('999.999.999-99');
        $('#id').val(oldVal)
      }
    }else if(val.length == 0) {
      $('#id').unmask();
    }
  });
}());
```

Fortunately the mask is correctly applied. The problem is that the first char is being lost.

Example:

1. When I type **012.345.678-99** the field gets **_12.345.678-99**.
2. Similarly when I type **#2001120001** the field gets **_2001120001**.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: The first char is lost due the mask plugin.

Comment: And can't I overcome that?

Comment: Do you know the plugin name? Maybe you can overcome that putting a default prefix for '#' and something else to avoid the non zero start.

Comment: Is it feasible to always mask onBlur, and mask onSubmit if field is not masked already?

Comment: It's JQuery mask plugin (http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/).

Comment: MonkeyZeus I must apply it on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for, but...

The plugin tries to apply the mask on every keypress. Altering the mask a little bit (and the translation, because "#" is considered to be a digit placeholder) lets the plugin handle the whole input line and mask it.

```
if (oldVal == '#') {
    $('#id').mask('#999999999', {"translation": {"#": null}});
    $('#id').val(oldVal);
} else {
    $('#id').mask('999.999.999-99');
    $('#id').val(oldVal);
}
```

It works in this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/FfR8j/2/

Again, not sure if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Matt the fiddle is doing exactly what I'd like. Your code have made my script runs properly for the # case. However it has same problem with the second case (mask '999.999.999-99'). My jquery version is 2.0. Any other thought?

Answer (score 1):

I used following code to mask Australian contact number field. Masking rules will be updated as the user enter first two or four digits:

```
// contactNumberOptions
var contactNumberOptions =  {onKeyPress: function(cep, e, field, options){
    var masks = ['00 0000 0000', '0000 000 000', '0000 0000'];

    var prefix2 = cep.substring(0, 2);
    var prefix3 = cep.substring(0, 5);
    var prefix4 = cep.substring(0, 4);

    mask = masks[2];

    if( prefix2 == '02' || prefix2 == '03' || prefix2 == '07' || prefix2 == '08'){
        mask = masks[0];
    } else if( prefix2 == '04'){
        mask = masks[1];
    } else if( prefix4 == '1800' || prefix4 == '1900' || prefix4 == '1902'){
        mask = masks[1];
    } else  {
        mask = masks[2];
    }

    jQuery('input[name=contact-number]').mask(mask, options);

}};

jQuery('input[name=contact-number]').mask('0000 0000', contactNumberOptions);
```